# Im trying to get my imageView to be invisible until I click a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I want my imageView in android studio to be invisible until i get a button to show that specific image, what sort of code would i use to set it that way.

I have had little to no success with any previous knowledge I have with android.

Comment: Can you share the details of your codes?